# jQuery: How can select clicked element in table without define unique id for each element

Tags: jquery

I have table (that generated by server) below.
I want to get input element value `class="itemQuantity"` of clicked row. 
I write jQuery code but he missing "this" of clicked element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.updateButton').click(function() {
        alert($('.itemQuantity').val());
    });
});
</script>
```

How can I do it with jQuery (I thinking to use this and not create id for each element, but I have low knowledge in jQuery).

Thanks,
Yosef

```
<table id="items">
<tr>
<th>item id</th>
<th>item name</th>
<th>item quantity</th>
<th>item update</th>
</tr>
<tr>

<td class="itemID">
1
</td>

<td class="itemName">
Ferari
</td>
<td >
<input class="itemQuantity" type="text" size="4" />
</td>
<td>
<button class="updateButton">update item</button>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td class="itemID">
2
</td>

<td class="itemName">
Fiat
</td>
<td >
<input class="itemQuantity" type="text" size="4" />
</td>
<td>
<button class="updateButton">update item</button>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td class="itemID">
3
</td>

<td class="itemName">
Hundai
</td>
<td >
<input class="itemQuantity" type="text" size="4" />
</td>
<td>
<button class="updateButton">update item</button>
</td>
</tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.updateButton').click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('.itemQuantity').val());
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery event handlers "this" will refer to the DOM element that is the source of the event. So in your click() function you can use either this or $(this) if you need a wrapped object.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is fixed you can also achieve the same result with parent():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.updateButton').click(function() {
      alert($(this).parent().parent().find('.itemQuantity').val());
    });
  });
</script>
```